# where is token stored in backend, when we use mern stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt

How or where are token stored to keep token and user mapping, when we use jsonwebtoken in nodejs, express, mongoose, mongodb?

Comment: Depends on the details, but JWTs usually aren’t stored anywhere, that’s the point. They contain all the info they need within themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact architecture. If you have a backend which gets access tokens from an Authorization Server to access some API, and a separate frontend, it is common to have a session created for the frontend user and then keep entries in a database where the user's session is tied to the access token.

If it is your SPA or mobile client which gets access tokens, usually you can store them in memory.

If you're implementing an Authorization Server then you might not need to store access tokens, if you're issuing JWTs (as deceze noted, JWTs contain all the data). You need to keep them in a database if you issue opaque tokens, or you need to be able to revoke tokens.

So it really depends on your setup and what are you exactly doing.